# valid result in phpmyadmin but null result in json

Tags: php, mysql, json

The query is returning a valid result in phpmyadmin but when encoding in json all values are null:

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"websem_university") or die("could not connect database");
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
    $qu="select ".$table.".".$column.", ".$table.".".$condition_code.", id, ".$condition_degree.", univLinkImg.Link from ".$table.", univLinkImg where ".$condition_faculty."='".$faculty."' and ".$table.".".$condition_code."='".$uni."' and univLinkImg.code='".$uni."'";
    $stmt=$con->prepare($qu);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($major,$university,$code,$id,$degree,$link);

    $majors=array();
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $temp=array();
                $temp["maj"]=$major;
                $temp["univ"]=$university;
                $temp["code"]=$code;
                $temp["id"]=$id;
                $temp["degree"]=$degree;
                $temp["link"]=$link;
                echo $link;
                array_push($majors, $temp);
        }
            echo json_encode($majors, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Does json_last_error_msg() report anything (after you run json_encode). Any specific reason you chose that encoding option rather than just default? Also have you narrowed down (by experimentation) any data which might be causing a failure specifically? We can't see any of your data and you don't seem to have done any error checking or debugging, so we can only guess, really. We can't run your code, so you need to give us more information.

Comment: Generic debugging tip: print everything to see where something went wrong

Comment: I used this decoding because some information are in Arabic language.. I tried to print all data after getting it and they are all null.. What more info can I provide you?

Comment: print the values of `$stmt` between each line where you use it, and `$qu` and add it to your question. Find the first line in the code where something isn't equal to what you think it should be equal to

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it's because the number of variables in `bind_result` was more than selected columns

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).